# Darwin Streaming Server - Adaptive Bitrate?

Tags: streaming, quicktime, darwin, 3gp

Can anyone provide any direction or links on how to use the adaptive bitrate feature that DSS says it supports? According to the release notes for v6.0.3:

- 3GPP Release 6 bit rate adaptation support

I assume that this lets you include multiple video streams in the 3gp file with varying bitrates, and DSS will automatically serve the best stream based on the current bandwidth. At least that's what I hope it does.

I guess I'm not sure what format DSS is expecting to receive the file. I tried just adding several streams to a 3gp file which resulted in Quicktime unable to play it, and VLC opening up a different window for each stream in the file.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Adaptive streaming used in DSS 6.x uses a dropped frame approach to reduce overall bandwidth rather than dynamic on the fly bitrate adjustments. The result of this can be unpredictable. The DSS drops the frames, and does not need the video encoded in any special way for it to work.